# what iOS device info can I get from MDM server?

Tags: ios, mdm, udid

I am an enterprise developer developing iOS MDM services. I have find some information from 
http://www.joshwright.com/tips/getting-an-iphone-udid-from-mobile-safari. 
what I want to know is:
The article above mentioned "Apple allows developers to get a person's UDID (& do many other things) through a special interaction between the phone and your web server. "

What "other things" could the server get from iphone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is not short because Enterprise MDM allows to do a LOT of things. 
I can separate all abilities in 2 big groups:

- Get some information from device (UDID, iOS version, IMEI and etc.). Example usage you can find in http://get.udid.io that uses MDM Solution to provide you info about your device.
- Configure something on device (network settings, enable/disable features and etc.)

This is the answer in short. But the full answer is really big and you can find this information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html

Is that what you want to know?

Comment: Thanks Vanger, your answer is helpful!